# Spring MVC WebBindingInitializer not being called

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, initialization

In a Controller defined with `@Controller`, configured by `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`, I used to have this:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinderAll(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(DATE_FMT, true));
}
```

Wanting this configuration in many Controllers, I created a `org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebBindingInitializer` and implemented

```
@Override
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(DATE_FMT, true));
}
```

I wired this in with

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer" ref="myWebBindingInitializer"/>
</bean>
```

It seems to not be picked up. Why not?

(I feel that [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8648) may have something to do with it, but I don't get the comment "I'm resolving this as invalid since the sample code isn't how we would recommend to do it.")

Spring version is `4.2.5.RELEASE`

Comment: I recommend to use `@ControllerAdvice` instead.

Comment: Thanks; didn't know about this. I'll give it a go. Would you care to post as an answer? If it works out, I'll accept.